# Creating Activity feed using Web Sockets in Spring

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-boot

I have a dashboard, that displays latest entered users and some additional information which I get in these services:

```
@JsonView(View.SurveyWithClients.class)
@RequestMapping(value="getData/{gender}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Info> getTopUsers(@PathVariable("gender") char gender) {
    List<Info> info=infoService.findByClient_GenderOrderByInfoResults(gender);
    return info;

}
```

And this one :

```
 @JsonView(View.SurveyWithClients.class)
@RequestMapping(value="getActivityFeed",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Info> getLatestActivity() {
    return infoService.findTop5ByOrderBySubmittedDateDesc();

}
```

What I'm currently doing, is I make an ajax call to these two endpoints and get the data to display in divs.
But what I have read to be a better solution is to use web sockets so that the view is updated in real time.

Is it the endpoints that I need to pass into, or the service layer?
How would the structure of the code look like ? What's the logical path to follow to achieve this ?
I've only seen examples where they're used for a chat application, but I dont know how to do it with such calculations and data.
Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: You can use websockets but as the name suggests it is a socket, which can send and receive data to and from client(browser) but there is no mapping as to which function should get called based on a path. Spring supports STOMP protocol on top of websockets, which allows you call different functions from client side like HttpRequest. Regarding updating view on on client in realtime is what AngularJs and Ember.js can do, I am not sure about react.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about 2 way channel for your feed web socket would make sense, if you are talking about 1 way it will make sense also but you need to keep in mind that there are many other trends which can be used using http.

When using websocket you are using different protocol (not HTTP) the connection will be established using HTTP but after that a websocket will be opened for the communication separated from the HTTP protocol, this in my opinion is good specially that browsers have limited ability to do concurrent HTTP requests.

I mentioned a Methodology to create the feed using websocket and message broker in this post 
[Designing Complex Notification system in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344181/designing-complex-notification-system-in-spring)

all you need is to include websock dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket/5.0.2.RELEASE

also you need to configure the websocket in your spring application

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig  implements WebSocketConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private NotificationHandler notificationHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("handler registered for websocket");
        registry.addHandler(notificationHandler,  "/questions")//define the endpoint for the websocket with handler to all the messages
        .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS(); //allow CRSF

    }
```

My handler which is used to push to a specific clients

```
@Component
public class NotificationHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private Map<Integer, WebSocketSession> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> userToSessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        sessions.put(Integer.valueOf(session.getId()), session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Session Id: " + session.getId());
        System.out.println("Session Id: " + session.getId());

        System.out.println("Extracted session ID " + sessions.get(Integer.valueOf(session.getId())).getId());
         String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(message.getPayload());
         if(username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
             return;
         } else if(!userToSessionMap.containsKey(username)) {
             userToSessionMap.put(username, new ArrayList<Integer>());
             userToSessionMap.get(username).add(Integer.valueOf(session.getId()));
         } else if(!userToSessionMap.get(username).contains(Integer.valueOf(session.getId()))) {
             userToSessionMap.get(username).add(Integer.valueOf(session.getId()));
         }

         try {
            sessions.get(Integer.valueOf(session.getId())).sendMessage(new TextMessage("new message recieved"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessageToUserSessions(User user, String message) {
        Notification notification = notificationService.createNotification(user, message);
        List<Integer> sessionsList = userToSessionMap.get(user.getUsername());
        if(sessionsList == null || sessionsList.isEmpty())//no available sessions (makes no sense, need to check with UI)
            return;
        for(Integer sessionId: sessionsList) {
            WebSocketSession session = sessions.get(sessionId);
            if(session != null)
                try {
                    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(notification.toJsonString()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                };
        }
    }

}
```